# how to explicitly draw svg viewbox coordinates

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, viewbox

I have an svg viewbox element to draw waveform as follows:

```
<svg id="waveform" viewBox="0 -1 2000 2" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <g id="waveform">
    <path id="waveform1" d="{{some data}}"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

It plots the waveform as expected. However it doesn't give me the x and y label of the viewbox, is there any alternate way by which we can add the x and y label of viewbox on webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Your svg is rendering a single path, the waveform. If you want labeled axes to be drawn, you need to render them. For example, inspect the source of these SVG graphs with labeled axes: http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph-titles.php. You'll probably want to use a library to do this.

The `svg` element is not a "smart" graphing widget, it is a plain canvas.

The `viewbox` attribute on the `svg` element sets the coordinate system within which the content of the svg is drawn (its internal dimensions, as opposed to the actual pixel dimensions when it is rendered).

Comment: Thanks for the response. and I agree that svgs are not very smart in handling graphics. so trying the to get the waveform using highcharts now. Appreciate your response.